# Palindrome checker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've built a Palindrome checker in JavaScript. It's fairly simple.

I'm still learning JS and am looking to learn.

So I would love hear ideas on how to improve the JavaScript in this. Like more efficient ways to resolve the task of checking for Palindrome.

Source code is below. Link to CodePen is her: http://codepen.io/MarkBuskbjerg/pen/JWMWwN?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div class="cover">
    <div class="container header">
        <div class="row row-margin">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Palindrome checker</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="text-center text-uppercase">A nut for a jar of tuna</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-margin">
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea class="col-md-12" id="inputPalindrome" rows="5">Borrow or rob?</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-margin">
            <div class="col-sm-3">

            </div>
            <button id="checkPalindrome" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4" type="submit">Check palindrome</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-margin">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <div id="notification" class="alert alert-info">Palindrome has not been checked yet</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cover {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row-margin {
  margin: 4vh auto;
}

body {
  background: #FF4E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
}

.header {
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Pacifico";
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

JavaScript:

```
var checkButton = document.getElementById("checkPalindrome");

function isPalindrome(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0123456789]+/g,"");
    var reversedStr = str.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (str == reversedStr) {
        return true
    } 
    return false
}

checkButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var palindromeInput = document.getElementById("inputPalindrome").value;
    var palindromeReturn = isPalindrome(palindromeInput);
    if(palindromeReturn === true) {
        document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Yay! You've got yourself a palindrome";
        document.getElementById("notification").className = "alert alert-success";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Nay! Ain't no palindrome";
        document.getElementById("notification").className = "alert alert-danger";
    }
});
```

Link to CodePen with the Palindrome Checker
http://codepen.io/MarkBuskbjerg/pen/JWMWwN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### RegEx

In character class, `0123456789` can be written as range `0-9`. Although, this has no effect on working of RegEx, it saves some keystrokes and looks consistent with alphabets range `a-z`.

### toLowerCase after replace

First remove the special characters and then convert the string to lower case. This, in my opinion will run fast than other way round as the number of characters to work on are reduced.(Not Tested)

When doing this, don't forget to add `i` flag on the RegEx.

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, "").toLowerCase();
```

### return boolean;

```
if (str == reversedStr) {
    return true
} 
return false
```

can be written as `return str == reversedStr`. It is also recommended to use strict equality operator.

```
return str === reversedStr;
```

See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/2025923)

### Caching DOM element reference

In the click handler of button, `#notification` is referenced four times. All times, it is read again from DOM. This can be slower. The element can be cached and used whenever required.

```
var notification = document.getElementById('notification');
...
...
notification.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
```

---

### Complete Code

Updated after [suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158599/palindrome-checker-in-javascript/158605?noredirect=1#comment300441_158605) from [Ismael Miguel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53773/ismael-miguel)

```
// After DOM is completely loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    "use strict";

    // Cache
    var palindromeInput = document.getElementById("inputPalindrome");
    var notification = document.getElementById("notification");

    function isPalindrome(str) {
        str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, "").toLowerCase();
        return str.split("").reverse().join("") === str;
    }

    document.getElementById("checkPalindrome")
        .addEventListener("click", function() {

            if (isPalindrome(palindromeInput.value)) {
                notification.innerHTML = "Yay! You've got yourself a palindrome";
                notification.className = "alert alert-success";
            } else {
                notification.innerHTML = "Nay! Ain't no palindrome";
                notification.className = "alert alert-danger";
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: `if (isValuePalindrome === true)` can just be `if(isPalindrome(value))`

Comment: Nice. Thanks a bunch for these tips and great explanations. Great help Tushar

Comment: `var notification = document.getElementById('notification');` isnt actually needed at all. In chrome at least, all ids are already defined as global variables.

Comment: @Kaspars not needed, but it's good practice to be explicit. If you add another script which happens to overwrite the global variable `notification` (which isn't completely ridiculous, that's quite a well-used word) then you'd introduce a really weird bug by doing something that shouldn't ever affect this script

Comment: If you do `toLowerCase()` *after* the `replace()` you need to update your replace to include the `A-Z` class as well, right? So `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`, not `[^a-z0-9]`

Comment: @CreationEdge no, he's using the `i` flag on the regex which matches everything case-insensitively. Also you added in an underscore, which you wouldn't want to check as part of the palindrome

Comment: @Joe Duh, missed the `i`! I didn't mean to add the underscore, though, please ignore! (Copy & paste error).

Comment: As an improvement, `0-9` can be written as `\d`, with no side effects. `'use strict';` is being used twice. You can put it on the top and it takes effect everywhere. You should store `document.getElementById("inputPalindrome")` and `document.getElementById('notification')` in variables **outside** the click handler. Also, you have mixed quote styles. I recommend using double-quotes (`"`) for this case. Also `'Yay! You\'ve got yourself a palindrome'` is needlessly escaped, and should be in double-quotes. Also, the whole code should be wrapped inside a `window.onload = function(){ ... };`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Those are really good suggestions. I've made changes accordingly except `\d` where I think `0-9` is more clear and consistent with `a-z`. Thanks for all the suggestions. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I still recomment `window.onload` over `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", [...]);`, but, for this code, it won't make a difference. And yes, the `\d` is harder to read for those who don't know it's meaning. But it's worth mentioning it in your answer, right?

Comment: @Tushar: I've tested whether putting `toLowerCase()` after `replace()` will be more efficient in this case and it turns out that it will. But it would be even better to drop the `+` from regex altogether, since the `g` flag makes it redundant. [Screenshot of benchmark](https://i.imgur.com/zKfGMbg.png).

Answer (score 8):

I'll just add a couple of observations to [Tushar's existing answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158605/106887), as that's a very solid teeing-off point.

### Remove global scope

At present, your code is all going into the global scope of the document. If you happen to use another script on the page, it's possible (although in this case likely) that something else may also define an `isPalindrome` function. By using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) you can eliminate the risk of this happening:

```
(function () {
    function isPalindrome (str) {
        // ...
    }

    document.getElementById("checkPalindrome")
        // ...
}());
```

A bonus of doing this, as pointed out by Ismael Miguel in comments, is that you can then extract the `'use strict'` into the outside function, preventing the need to repeat it.

### Consistent quotes

You're using a mish-mash of single quotes and double quotes; for example you have `getElementById("checkPalindrome")` but then `getElementById('notification')` later on. More notably, you set `innerHTML = 'Yay! You\'ve` in the `true` block, but then `innerHTML = "Nay! Ain't` in the `false` block.

Generally speaking I'd recommend using single quotes 99% of the time but using double quotes [if the string contains another single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149192/difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript).

### Comments should make sense

Simple enough one here - what does "value is much clear" mean? In fairness, this is probably just a comment directed at you, from Tushar, but still... it's not the kind of comment you'd write in your production code. I'm just mentioning this for completeness sake more than anything else.

```
// value is much clear
var value = document.getElementById("inputPalindrome").value;
```

### Unnecessary characters in regex

Another very minor one - these two regexes are identical:

```
/[^a-z0-9]+/gi
/[^a-z0-9]/gi
```

Because you have the `g` modifier (global - match every occurrence), you don't need the `+` symbol in the regex (one or more occurrences).

### Combine multiple `var` statements

This one is [purely down to your preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781406/javascript-variable-definition-commas-vs-semicolons), but I generally feel that combining multiple `var` statements into one block reduces noise in the code and makes it easier to scan.

```
var value = document.getElementById('inputPalindrome').value,
    notification = document.getElementById('notification');
```

### Name your closures

Something that you may not know is that in your anonymous click handler function, you can actually give it a function name:

```
.addEventListener("click", function checkPalindrome () {
```

There's one significant benefit of doing this: when you're debugging something in the console, [if you name your functions then their names will show up in the stack trace](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/38174n/why_dont_we_name_our_anonymous_functions/).

### Extract closures if they contain significant logic

This is again more of a personal preference; your `checkPalindrome` function is doing a fair bit of work, so rather than just declaring it inline I'd personally declare it separately then just pass the reference to it into the `.addEventListener` call.

```
function checkPalindrome () {
    'use strict';
    // ...
}

document.getElementById('checkPalindrome')
    .addEventListener('click', checkPalindrome);
```

Another nice bonus is that it removes a level of indentation from your code; generally speaking, the more indents you have, the harder it is for someone else (or you in two months time) to pick up the code and understand.

### Hoist DOM lookups outside of the click handler

Another point raised by Ismael Miguel below; we can move the `document.getElementById` calls out of the click handler so they only get evaluated once. In this scenario it's a micro-optimisation but if you have handlers which can be called on many elements in quick succession, it's a very good habit to be in.

### Complete Code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var value = document.getElementById('inputPalindrome').value,
        notification = document.getElementById('notification');

    function isPalindrome (str) {
        str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
        return str.split('').reverse().join('') === str;
    }

    function checkPalindrome () {
        if (isPalindrome(value)) {
            notification.innerHTML = "Yay! You've got yourself a palindrome";
            notification.className = 'alert alert-success';
        } else {
            notification.innerHTML = "Nay! Ain't no palindrome";
            notification.className = 'alert alert-danger';
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('checkPalindrome')
        .addEventListener('click', checkPalindrome);
}());
```

Comment: I like your answer +1. Except two things `+` on character class is faster and if you miss a comma in multiple var declaration, following variables will be global.

Comment: @Tushar both valid comments - there's no clear cut right or wrong either way. My approach is that both of those are (in most cases) the tiniest of micro-optimisations; over the course of your entire lifetime (not just the application's lifetime, but yours) the optimisations won't even save one second of processing time. In that scenario, I tend towards what I think is slightly more readable. You may disagree and that's totally fine, so long as you understand why you're doing it :-)

Comment: Small improvements: You should use `window.onload = function(){ ... };` instead of a self-calling anonymous function. Also, you should store all `document.getElementById(...)` **outside** the event handler. You did the right thing in using double quotes instead of escaping, but you aren't consistent about it. You should replace the single-quotes with double-quotes, to keep it consistent. Also, on your regular expression, you can write `\d` instead of `0-9`. You are using `'use strict';` twice. Put it as the first line and you're done. [...]

Comment: [...] Also, about condencing multiple `vars` into one may be prone to errors. It may be slightly faster, but that's it. If you forget a quote at the end, you suddenly have a global variable. Bad, bad idea... Using multiple `var`s is *explicitly* saying "This is a local variable". With a single `var`, you are forced to check the end of the line above to know if it is a local or a global variable.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel do you have a source for `window.onload` vs IIFE? I'm interested :-) Re consistency, I use single quotes unless I want a single quote in the value, then I'll use double quotes. In this small app it's possible to exclusively say "I only use double quotes", but in larger apps you'll want both single and double quotes in different strings. Re variable declarations; indenting tells you. Sure it's not foolproof, but with an auto-formatting and code smelling IDE it's easy to spot. Agreed on everything else

Comment: @Joe About `window.onload`, that's easy: `window.onload` will be dispached once all the content on the page is ready (DOM, scripts, CSS, images, ...), while a self-executing anonimous function will run whever it is found. Which can be **before any** of the elements you fetch with `document.getElementById(...)` exists in the DOM. This will throw errors and do ... nothing. About single and double quotes, I believe it is a preference, but consistency is important. About variable declaration, it is easy to spot on those, but still not fool-proof. [...]

Comment: [...] The only fool-proof way is to write multiple  `var`s. [And one of the most popular development tools is Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=hero-questions#technology-most-popular-developer-environments-by-occupation), which doesn't have a built-in plugin for Javascript formatting. You have to go to 3rd party websites (e.g.: http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/) to download it. So, don't assume that that amazing feature is available. I see more disadvantages with 1 single `var`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel fair point about quotes. For `window.onload`, the script should be at the bottom of the page, directly before the `</body>` tag so all elements should have loaded in before the script executes, no? As I understand it, that's the entire point of putting scripts after all content. On IDEs, fair point; I guess it comes down more to house styling at that point (in fairness, a lot of nitpicky things come down to house styling, I feel - there's no definitive right way and no great arguments for either way being objectively better).

Comment: @Joe You're right about  `window.onload`. Putting the script at the bottom will eliminate most of the need to have it there. But, that code is executed once the HTML there is parsed. That means that images, styles and what-not haven't loaded. `window.onload` is only dispached after that. For this code, one can *kinda* skip using it. But if you're going to use a self-executing function, might as well just use `window.onload`. About  `var`s, it comes down to preference, yes. But, it has the benefict of being a safe-guard in case you forget a comma. But yours looks better, I agree.

Comment: @Joe: You are not updating your `value` inside a click handler.

Answer (score 4):

I have two objections to the Javascript function as written, both as submitted and as
rewritten by other commenters:

1. It is fairly difficult to inspect or test.  All the steps are
   intertwined.  If you had forgotten, for example, to handle upper-case,
   you might very well not have noticed in all that code.
2. All you end up with is one, not very useful function.  How likely
   is it that in the future you will again need a function to determine
   is a string is a palindrome considering only down-cased alphanumerics?

My proposal is this:

```
const arrayFunctionOnString = (s, f) => f(s.split("")).join("");

const reverseString = s => arrayFunctionOnString(s, d => d.reverse());

const cleanString = s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, "");

const isPalindrome = s => s === reverseString(s);

const isLoosePalindrome = s => isPalindrome(cleanString(s));
```

Not only is each step easy to examine and test in isolation, but when
you are done, you have a nonce function, `isLoosePalindrome()` for the problem at hand, one
possibly useful function, `isPalindrome()`, and three new functions
that you will definitely need again in the future.

**Edit:**

Or, if you got excited, you could write:

```
const compose = (f, g) => x => f(g(x));

const isLoosePalindrome = compose(isPalindrome, cleanString)
```

Answer (score 0):

## You need to remove whitespace characters as well.

Race Car is also a palindrome, but with your current code race car would be reversed to "rac ecar" and give a false negative.

You can get this functionality by adding the following code to your isPalindrome function.

```
var variableName = variableName.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can solve it without using regular expressions or reversing the string by just comparing the first and last characters (ignoring any characters that do not meet your requirements - i.e. non-alphanumeric characters) and then iterating inwards from both ends until you reach the middle of the string:

```js
function isValidPalindromeCharacter( char ){
  return ( 'A' <= char && char <= 'Z' )
      || ( 'a' <= char && char <= 'z' )
      || ( '0' <= char && char <= '9' );
}

function isCharactersEqual( a, b ){
  return a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase();
  // return (a.charCodeAt(0)|32) == (b.charCodeAt(0)|32);
}

function isPalindrome(str){
  var lower = 0,
      upper = str.length - 1;
  while ( true )
  {
    while ( lower < upper && !isValidPalindromeCharacter( str[lower] ) )
    {
      lower++;
    }
    while ( lower < upper && !isValidPalindromeCharacter( str[upper] ) )
    {
      upper--;
    }
    if ( lower >= upper )
    {
      return true;
    }
    if ( !isCharactersEqual( str[lower], str[upper] ) )
    {
      return false;
    }
    lower++;
    upper--;
  }
}

var palindrome   = document.getElementById("inputPalindrome");
var notification = document.getElementById('notification');

document.getElementById("checkPalindrome")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    'use strict';

    // value is much clear
    var value = palindrome.value;

    if (isPalindrome(value)) {
        notification.innerHTML = 'Yay! You\'ve got yourself a palindrome';
        notification.className = "alert alert-success";
    } else {
        notification.innerHTML = "Nay! Ain't no palindrome";
        notification.className = "alert alert-danger";
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <textarea id="inputPalindrome" rows="5">Borrow or rob?</textarea>
  <button id="checkPalindrome" type="button">Check palindrome</button>
  <div id="notification">Palindrome has not been checked yet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically true, but your `isPalindrome` function just went from 3 lines to 25 lines, gained 2 index variables (`i` and `j`), 3 `while` loops (2 of which are nested)... and that's just the obvious stuff. Regexes are a good thing, not a bad thing (so long as you know when it's appropriate to use them)

Comment: @Joe Regular expressions are much slower than comparing characters and so is creating 2 arrays (using `.split()` and `.reverse()`) and then creating an entirely new string `.join()` before finally doing a comparison of the entire string. This way you only need to compare the front of the string to the end of the string and do not create new data structures.

Comment: Well, apart from [it actually being slower than using a regex](https://jsfiddle.net/gfgurxa7/1/), you may have had a point. Even if it was faster though, the complexity you add for a micro-optimisation is grossly over-doing it, **unless** you happen to need that optimisation. For general usage, and certainly for professional usage, you'd take the 3-line regex solution every day of the week until it's found to be causing a bottleneck

Comment: Its true that his is a lot longer than the original code but there is a lot of extra stuff. It could be shortened considerably: `...; for(let lower=0, upper=str.length-1;upper>lower; lower++, upper--) { if str[lower] != str[upper] return false }; return true`. If this was an interview test this is the solution I would probably want to see.

Comment: @MarcRohloff in that case, with the best will in the world, I hope you're never interviewing me for a job :P I disagree that it does "a lot of extra stuff" and that in an interview for a job you're looking for someone who can write 25 LOC when 3 LOC will suffice. That said, it's the Internet, you're your own person and far be it from me to criticise :-)

Comment: @Joe, you misunderstand, what I'm saying is that most interviewers would want to see a thought out, optimized, solution rather than a naive string reversal. Also my solution is only 5 lines.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." -- Donald Knuth